# Handle async http error with try and catch statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I hope this is an easy one:**

I am trying to implement error handling within a try and catch statement in a ReactJS action creator.

```
export const getUserKitchens = () => async dispatch => {
    try{
        const response = await axios.get(
            `${baseURL}customer/get-user-kitchens/`,
         )
        dispatch({type:LOAD_USER_KITCHENS, payload: response.data})
    } catch(e) {
        const msg = "something"
        dispatch(displayStatus(msg, true))
    }
}
```

If the request fails with an HTTP status of 401 I want to log out the user. Therefore, I need to have access to the Http response headers from the catch statement and retrieve the HTTP status from there.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: The `e` object in the catch statement is an error object. You could access the status code with `error.response.status` and the headers with `error.response.headers`. Is this what you asked for or were you asking for a global configuration on the `axios` object where you log out if any response is `401` code?

Comment: Great! No, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Ok added the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54996764/5223309) to the question. Please accept it if it does for you what you were looking for. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `e` object in the `catch` statement is an error object. You could access the status code with `error.response.status` and the headers with `error.response.headers`. Something like this should be useful:

```
export const getUserKitchens = () => async dispatch => {
    try{
        const response = await axios.get(
            `${baseURL}customer/get-user-kitchens/`,
         )
        dispatch({type:LOAD_USER_KITCHENS, payload: response.data})
    } catch(e) {
        const status = e.response.status;
        if (status === 401) {
           dispatch({type:LOG_USER_OUT}) //LOG_USER_OUT is a logout action
        } else {
          dispatch(displayStatus(status, true))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [`await MDN docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

> The await expression causes async function execution to pause until a
>   Promise is resolved, that is fulfilled or rejected, and to resume
>   execution of the async function after fulfillment. When resumed, the
>   value of the await expression is that of the fulfilled Promise.
>
> If the Promise is rejected, the await expression throws the rejected
>   value.

So if there is an API error, the error object is being throws which you get in the `catch` block and can access the status and headers from it with `error.response.status` and `error.response.headers`

```
export const getUserKitchens = () => async dispatch => {
    try{
        const response = await axios.get(
            `${baseURL}customer/get-user-kitchens/`,
         )
        dispatch({type:LOAD_USER_KITCHENS, payload: response.data})
    } catch(e) {
        const status = e.response.status;
        dispatch(displayStatus(status, true))
    }
}
```